# Latest 18.04.1 not working on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, downloads

I downloaded the LTS version of ubuntu off the webpage and upon install to Virtualbox the error message says my pc is not 64bit. my pc is only i686? I use a hp pavilion x360 with windows 10. I thought it was 64 bit?
message says: This kernel requires requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot. Please use a kernel appropriate for your PC. 
any help?
Cheers

Comment: Maybe this message is from Ubuntu running as a guest _on_ VirtualBox? In which case, it is the VirtualBox guest you created for Ubuntu that isn't 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE: GO to Bios and set Virtualization and Hyper-v to ENABLE*** in ubuntu as well.

(This will enble the option for 64-bit in all os) by default it is DISABLED

just restart and goto BIOS and you are good to go.